# Dynamic setting of TCP window scaling option

Tags: tcp, default-value

When I am trying to change window scale options, as a root I am able to change the values by doing `net.ipv4.tcp_mem=16777000` in `/proc/sys/net/`. If I have to change this 100 systems its a lot of work. SO, how can I dynamically change this value instead of manually changing it in every system?

Answer (score 1):

You can try running a script to affect it all the machines .
Similar to the below :

> USERNAME=someUser HOSTS="host1 host2 host3" SCRIPT="pwd; ls" for
>   HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
>       ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}" done